# Converting MS Office Docx with a good compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, syncfusion, document-conversion

After spending hours and hours on StackOverflow and programmers forum, i've decided to use the SyncFusion on our project. 
Our main target is :

1. convert to PDF/directly print existing Doc And Docx
2. this Document can be quite complexe (including shapes, images....)
3. using Word Interop can not be a solution for us

If we are able to convert or print without problems, the orginal Word documents are not well rendered (parts of shapes missing...)

Somebody is using this component without problem ? Or do you knows others best components (Aspose ??)

Comment: I know some solution exists, because the web site http://www.zamzar.com is coverting my Docuement perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can meet these requirements using Aspose.Words. With [Aspose.Words for .NET API](http://www.aspose.com/.net/word-component.aspx), you can easily render any complex Microsoft Word document or Text/Html/Mhtml file to PDF format with high fidelity. Please see the following simple code:

```
// Load Word document in memory for processing
Document doc = new Document(MyDir + "Document.docx");
// Send it directly to printer
doc.Print("printerName");
// Convert DOCX to PDF
doc.Save(MyDir + "DocxToPdf.pdf");
```

This means that if you convert a Microsoft Word document into PDF, XPS or print it using Aspose.Words, the output will appear almost exactly as if it was done by Microsoft Word application. Please check [Aspose.Words for .NET Documentation](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Home) for more details.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: I'v tried your solution, it is working very well in most case. But i wouldn't be so enthousiast about "appear almost exactly". In fact we have some problem when rendering text box with decoration, especially when some of them are overlapping each others.  Are you awere about such a problem. Maybe i can send you an example.

Comment: Sure, please report this issue in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx). Please attach your input Word document and Aspose.Words generated output PDF file showing the undesired behavior in your thread for testing. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: OK, i will end you exemple documents asap (but i am busy for few days on other project)

Comment: Hi, here is the document i want to print : https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/ac7cd815851e5e9203f0f1a200314b6a20151127131511/9e3f4727c43dd44d115a4a35218f2fb520151127131511/fec5e8

Comment: Yes, I can see a few problems when converting "TEST DOC SSN.docx" to PDF using Aspose.Words. Please start a new thread in [Aspose.Words forum](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/aspose.words-product-family/75/showforum.aspx) so that we can report these issues to our product team. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please send your example document to Syncfusion by creating a [support ticket](http://www.syncfusion.com/support/directtrac/incidents) and we will able to check and provide a solution. (I work for Syncfusion)

Comment: OK, i will end you exemple documents asap (but i am busy for few days on other project)

Comment: Hi, here is the document i want to print : https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/ac7cd815851e5e9203f0f1a200314b6a20151127131511/9e3f4727c43dd44d115a4a35218f2fb520151127131511/fec5e8

Comment: Thanks. In the given input Word document, shapes are preserved as Group shapes which are currently not supported in Word to Pdf/Image conversions. We have already logged this as feature request in our database. We are working to define the best possible way to achieve this.

Comment: @sstassin The feature has been implemented in our latest version (2016 Volume 2).

Answer (score 1):

Ty for all the answers (in this post and other on SO).
But after trying :

- 4 or 5 .Net Libraries
- Using very simple, but also complex Doc and Docx Files
- And specialy with complex doc file, mixing complex shapes, grouping schemes, img import....

Here is my conclusion (imo) :

- there is no better processing (printing and creating PDF) than using Ms Office and it's automation from .Net
- and even if it is not recommended by MS itseflf, we are very sastified of our "doc printing server"
- it is printing more than 30 or 50 "Build of Manufacturer" with more than 30 pages each, and also with A3 plan.
- it is working very well for 4 month, without major bug

If somebody is interested, i can post the tips and link i have used to properly use MS Office in a "Windows Printer Server mode".

Best regards from Toulouse

Answer (score 0):

Docentric Toolkit is primarily a mail merge library but also has a complete DOM and a high fidelity PDF/XPS rendering engine. Still I haven’t try to convert a Word document containing decorations and styles with effects.

```
document = Document.Load("Test1.docx");
document.Save("Test1.pdf");
```

Comment: Suited to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Ok i'll give it a try in few days, because at the moment i didn't find a solutions that have a "really perfect" render of ours existing word documents